# Parent method from child class not being called React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I have been working on  react native project and I ran into an issue.
here's my parent class:

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
  }
  state = {
    userDocExists: null
  };
  handler() {
    console.log("in handler");
    this.setState({
      userDocExists: true
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <UserInfo handler={this.handler} />;
  }
}
```

my child class:

```
class UserInfo extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  registerUser = () => {

  const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  firestore
    .collection("Users")
    .doc(userId)
    .set({
      firstName: this.state.firstName,
      houseNumber: this.state.houseNumber,
      CommunityId: this.state.CommunityId,
    })
    .then((docRef) => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      this.props.handler; //not being called
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });
} else {
  this.setState({ ErrorMes: true });
}
};
```

My this.props.handler is not being called for some reason. but when I use it in an OnPress of a button in the render , it works fine. Could someone tell me why this behaviour occurs?

Comment: Why is there an `else` without an `if` condition in your `UserInfo` component?

Comment: If I understand the problem, I believe you just have to actually call the function `this.props.handler()`. Don't forget the parenthesis :)

Comment: It should be called `this.props.handler()`. parenthesis is missing

Comment: Thanks guys. Sill mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.props.handler` will give you function definition but to call it You have to invoke it  `this.props.handler()` this trigger the function handler of the parent

```
class UserInfo extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  registerUser = () => {

  const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  firestore
    .collection("Users")
    .doc(userId)
    .set({
      firstName: this.state.firstName,
      houseNumber: this.state.houseNumber,
      CommunityId: this.state.CommunityId,
    })
    .then((docRef) => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    //this.props.handler;
      this.props.handler(); //Invoked the function
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });
} else {
  this.setState({ ErrorMes: true });
}
```